# Fibers vs. explicit enumerators

Tags: ruby, enumerator, fibers

I am toying around with Ruby to learn the language. Currently I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of fibers. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194052/2800551), they are fairly often used for creating (infinite) external enumerators. On the other hand, this seems to overlap with the concept of so called explicit enumerators.

Say, I want to write a code snippet that fires consecutive prime numbers (yes, the following algorithm has a runtime of O(scary)). I can implement it by using fibers:

```rb
prime_fiber = Fiber.new do
    primes = [2]
    Fiber.yield 2
    current = 1
    loop do
        current += 2 
        unless primes.find {|value| (current % value) == 0}
            Fiber.yield current
            primes << current
        end
    end
end

ARGV[0].to_i.times {print "#{prime_fiber.resume}, "}
```

This does not emit an enumerator object by itself, although it is not difficult to create one out of it. In contrast, I can also utilize an explicitly defined enumerator, which has the added benefit of already being an enumerator object:

```rb
prime_enum = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    primes = [2]
    yielder.yield 2
    current = 1 
    loop do
        current += 2
        unless primes.find {|value| (current % value) == 0}
            yielder.yield current
            primes << current
        end
    end
end

ARGV[0].to_i.times {print "#{prime_enum.next}, "}
# I could also write:
# p prime_enum.first(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

Both methods allow me to implement some sort of co-routines and they seem to be interchangeable to me. So when do I prefer one over the other? Is there some commonly agreed practice? I find it difficult to get all those idioms in my head, so I apologize in advance if this is considered a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Enumerator`, it allows you to use `take`, `take_while`, even `each` if your sequence is finite. While `Fiber` is designed for light weight concurrency and is pretty limited as enumerator.

```
prime_enum.take(ARGV[0].to_i).each { |x| puts x }
```

or

```
prime_enum.take_while { |x| x < ARGV[0].to_i }.each { |x| puts x }
```

Comment: So, I guess enumerators are recommended as long as mere _sequences_ of values are required and that I ought to use fibers if I want to stress the concurrency aspect of my code.